# Scala Duck Typing Newbie

Tags: scala

I'm poking around with Scala again and have what I hope will be a basic question regarding duck typing, or maybe it is really with function definitions.  Let me explain:

Given the following code:

```
package johnmcase.scala.oneoffs

object DuckTyping extends App {

  def printIt(x:Int, y:Int) = println("Value with " + x + " = " + y);

  // This method will accept ANY object that has a method named foo of type (Int) => Int
  def duckTyped(duck: {def foo: (Int) => Int}) = {
    List(1,2,3,4,5) foreach (i => printIt(i, duck.foo(i)))
  }

  println(new DoublerThatWontWork().foo(5))
  println(new Doubler().foo(5))
  println("DOUBLER:");
  duckTyped(new Doubler());
  println("Squarer:");
  duckTyped(new Squarer());
  println("AlwaysSeven:");
  duckTyped(new AlwaysSeven());
  println("DoublerThatWontWork :");
  duckTyped(new DoublerThatWontWork ()); // COMPILER ERROR!!
}

class DoublerThatWontWork { // WHY??
  def foo(x:Int) = x*2
}

class Doubler {
  def foo = (x:Int) => x*2
}

class Squarer {
  def foo = (x:Int) => x*x
}

class AlwaysSeven {
  def foo = (x:Int) => 7
}
```

So basically I have a method "duckTyped" that will accept ANY object as long as that object has a method named "foo" that is a Int=>Int function.

Why does the function declaration of foo in the class "DoublerThatWontWork" not satisfy the parameter type of function duckTyped?

Comment: Note: That's structual typing, not duck typing. The difference is subtle, but basically structual typing is checked up-front whereas duck-typed languages just go ahead and try it.

Comment: @delnan, the term "duck typing" only implies the "walks like a duck, quacks like a duck, therefore a duck" criterion. It does not specify whether it should be static or dynamic. Structural typing meets the criterion, and so can be called static duck typing. What dynamic typed languages have can be called dynamic duck typing (though "duck" is redundant there).

Comment: @missingfaktor I'm used to a different definition, as outlined above. Slightly more formally, I'd say the difference is: Structural typing *checks types* - statically or dynamically - based on structure (e.g. in Python: `hasattr(obj, attr)?`), whereas duck typing doesn't really check anything (e.g. just try and use the member, let the compiler/runtime complain if something's wrong). Note: I'm not saying anything about static or dynamic (C++ templates are duck-typed, yet typing is static and template instanciations *are* checked at compile time - just after the instanciation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your signature says there is a method foo with no parameters, which returns a function from Int to Int. What you have is a method with an Int parameter and an Int Result.

you want

```
duck: {def foo(i: Int) : Int}
```

(parameter name does not have to match)

Answer (score 4):

> So basically I have a method "duckTyped" that will accept ANY object
>   as long as that object has a method named "foo" that is a Int=>Int
>   function.

Actually, that's incorrect. To make it correct, change it to:

> a **parameterless** method named "foo" that **returns** an Int => Int function.

No method "is" an `Int => Int`, because that's a type, and methods don't have types (ie, they are not objects), just type signatures.

A type indicates what kind of object you are.

A type signature indicates how to call a method and what it returns.

And just to make it crystal clear, the two things below are not the same:

```
def f(x: Int): Int = x * 2
def f: Int => Int = x => x * 2
```

The first method returns an `Int`, and the second method returns an `Int => Int`. The first method has one parameter list, with one `Int` parameter while the second method has no parameter list.